# Divide second row Value with 1st row value for Same Column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

Please suggest me how to get the percentage by Divide second row Value with 1st row value for Same Column in  SRRS

EXAMPLE

DATSET ROWS

USAGE VALUE ADHERENT

1ST        75       -
2ND        50      71.42% (50/70)
3RD        40      80%

How to get Adherent values in SSRS.

Please advise

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the previous() function in an expression to calculate the percentage.

```
=Fields!Value.Value/Previous(Fields!Value.Value)
```

You will need to check for a previous value of 0 or null though to avoid dividing by zero.

[More info on previous() in SSRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255200(v=sql.110).aspx)